# How do I modify the Create Send SOAP API call to allow me to send to a data extension instead of a list?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api

The example SOAP envelope I downloaded to "Create Send" uses the  parameter to specify the email target.

I wish to send my email to a data extension instead of a list. How do I do this? Is it as straight forward as using a different parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP object for this is `SendDefinitionList`.

A sample portion of the SOAP envelope would be:

```
<!--  ID of the sendable data extension used as part of a send. -->
<SendDefinitionList>
     <CustomObjectID>1a3e2c14-580e-de11-b30f-001cc494ae9e</CustomObjectID>
     <DataSourceTypeID>CustomObject</DataSourceTypeID>
</SendDefinitionList>
```

Use this in place of the `List` attribute.